# Insert into table from select but change date to now()

Tags: python, mysql

How to copy data from table1, changing `ctime=NOW()` on inserted data in one query with table that does not contain unique row identifier on table2?

`INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE identifier = %s`

So, I need to update `ctime` in table2 to `NOW()` on moment of insert, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should specify the target columns for the insert, as well as listing out the columns in the select.

Comment: Name the columns in the `select` instead of using `*` and substitute the expression you want for the `table1` column you don't want.

Comment: Insert into table2 VALUES ("select my values"). I assume in your script you are not missing the "values" keyword?